# Difference between template function and auto arguments

Tags: templates, auto

I get the same result for both implemetation, what are the difference between using one vs the other?

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

template <typename T> T add_1(T a, T b)
{
   cout << "add_1: " <<  a+b << endl;
}

auto add_2(auto a, auto b)
{
   cout << "add_2: " << a+b << endl;
}

int main (void)
{
   add_1(10,20);
   add_1(9.8, 2.3);
   add_2(10,20);
   add_2(9.8, 2.3);
}
```

Thanks
Ratin